# How do I load Gleed 2D levels in WP7 XNA game?

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7, gleed2d

I've been trying so long to use this [modified version of GLEED2D](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D/wiki) that includes WP7 support,

I'm stuck into [loading the level](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D/wiki/LoadingALevelInYourGame) into my game, now my Game1.cs class has the following:

```
    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Content/leveltest.xml");
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(stream);
        level = LevelLoader.Load(xml);
        base.Initialize();
    }
```

I included the `XML` file of my level into `Content` Directory, when I try to build the solution, It gives this error:

```
XML is not in the XNA intermediate format. Missing XnaContent root element.
```

I didn't find any reference on how to fix it on the [developer's blog](http://stevedunns.blogspot.com/) or the [github WiKi](https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D/wiki)

Any Idea?

Comment: You need to look at this tutorial for loading XML in XNA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604979.aspx

Comment: @JohnMcDonald I just did that, what should I replace the "<Asset Type="MyDataTypes.PetData[]">" in the example with ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to **build** the XML file using the *XNA's Content Pipeline*. However, in the source code you posted, the XML file is being loaded at runtime using the LINQ to XML API (*XDocument*) so it doesn't need to go through the content pipeline.

To solve the problem, go to the **Solution Explorer**, browse into your Content project to your XML file, and then on its **Properties**, change the **Build Action** property from Compile to **Content**, and also enable the **Copy to Output Directory** property. See picture below:

[image]

This way your XML file will still be copied to the *Content* folder, without being built by the XNA's Content Pipeline.